# Write Tomcat 5.5 output to one of Tomcat's log files

Tags: java, logging, tomcat

I'd like that all the output that is shown in Tomcat's console will be saved into a file including the output on startup and shutdown of Tomcat.
How can I do this? 
I looked at [apache documentation about logging](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/logging.html), Do I need to change something in the logging.properties can I trust log4j to write message from the first message on startup to the last message on shutdown?

Answer (score 0):

Temporary workaround that I found is to change catalina.bat 
 
from set _EXECJAVA=start "Tomcat" %_RUNJAVA%  
to set _EXECJAVA=%_RUNJAVA% 
so running tomcat will not open new console but use the same one and when I suspend tomcat (ctrl c) It will not close the console so I could keep read the output.

Comment: Since nobody else answered better than my workaround for the last week, will mark it as the currently best answer...

Comment: I came to conclusion that this answer is not satisfying. So the answer is opened again - how do I make tomcat write to file its stdout???

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Solaris or similar try:

- nohup /path/to/tomcat/bin/startup.sh &

That'll write everything from the start to a file called nohup.out in the folder where you issued the command.

Don't know if that suites you thou.